# How to plot random x-values in gnuplot

Tags: matplotlib, gnuplot

I have a data set with two columns, `(x,y)` which looks like:

```
4 16
1 1
5 25
3 9
7 49
0 0
2 4
```

Now I want to plot this in gnuplot `u 1:2` in the order in which column 1 is arranged. Basically on x-axis, gnuplot should have first 4, then 1, then 5 and so on. Is it possible with gnuplot or any other plotting tool?

Comment: I fail to understand, why my answer was down-voted ! Please explain, so that this may be prevented in future...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With gnuplot you can use the row number as x-value and use the value from the first column as xtic labels:

```
plot 'data.txt' using 0:2:xtic(1) w lp pt 7 lw 2
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you also tagged `matplotlib`, here's a quick script to make the same plot. You just need to plot `y`, then set the `xticklabels` to `x`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x,y = np.genfromtxt('data.txt',unpack=True)

plt.plot(y,'ko-')
plt.gca().set_xticklabels(x)

plt.show()
```

[image]